# Cordova/PhoneGap -- edit files in /platforms/ or not?

Tags: cordova

I'm a longtime native iOS developer who's trying to school myself on Cordova/PhoneGap. I'm reading through the [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface)  and it seems to me there are two contradictory statements:

> WARNING: When using the CLI to build your application, you should not edit any files in the /platforms/ directory unless you know what you are doing, or if documentation specifies otherwise. The files in this directory are routinely overwritten when preparing applications for building, or when plugins are reinstalled.

And a little further down:

> The cordova build command is a shorthand for the following, which in this example is also
>       targeted to a single platform:

```
cordova prepare ios

cordova compile ios

In this case, once you run prepare, you can use Apple's Xcode SDK as an alternative to
modify and compile the platform-specific code that Cordova generates within
platforms/ios. You can use the same approach with other platforms' SDKs.
```

So...which is it? Am I not supposed to edit the platfom-specific files and instead work only in the /www/ directory? Or do I work on the platform-specific files?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are using the first approach i.e building the APP using `cordova prepare` **everytime** you **build** your project than the files in the **platform** directory will be overwritten. Whereas in the second approach you run the `cordova prepare` only **ONCE** and then use your native SDK development method to change the files in the **platform** directory for compiling and building. In the second approach you **never** again use the `cordova prepare` command as it will overwrite your files in the platform directory. Hopefully I have not confused you further :-)

Comment: Nope, that actually makes perfect sense. If you post this as an answer I'd be happy to accept it. Thanks!!!

Comment: posted the comment as the answer.. Happy coding :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the first approach i.e building the APP using `cordova prepare` **everytime** you build your project than the files in the **platform** directory will be **overwritten**.

Whereas in the **second** approach you run the `cordova prepare` only **ONCE** and then use your **native** SDK development method to change the files in the **platform** directory for compiling and building. 
In the second approach you **NEVER** again use the `cordova prepare` command as it will **overwrite** your files in the **platform** directory.