# Can't build Cordova iOS project using CLI but can build/run the Xcode project

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-cli

Absolutely new to Cordova. These are the steps I've done:

1. Checked out an existing project
2. run `cordova build ios`

The above generates this build error:

> (node:10242) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_UNHANDLED_ERROR]: Unhandled error. (The platform "ios" does not appear to be a valid cordova platform. It is missing API.js. ios not supported.)

I've Googled for a solution to the above and the general consensus seems to be to remove and then add the iOS platform.

Now there's a problem with that. Looking through the commit history, I can see that there have been code changes done to files within the `platforms` directory so I can't just remove it, or...

**Question 1)**
Can I?

**Question 2)**
Is it right to make code changes within the `platforms` directory? Because it seems like those are generated directories.

**Question 3)**
Why is it that when I open the Xcode project under `platforms/ios`, I am able to build/run it fine despite the Cordova CLI error above?

Comment: I came across this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27929283/cordova-phonegap-edit-files-in-platforms-or-not. Perhaps the previous developer used the second approach?

Comment: it's not right to manually edit the platform files. And some manual changes might make the project not build, so might be related to the manual changes somebody did. So if you don't want to risk to remove the platform, continue building from Xcode

Comment: @jcesarmobile Thanks. There also appears to be several changes to files under `src/js` as well as the same changes in `www` directory. Is it likely he made the same change manually in both places or would one have been generated from the other? For e.g, there's a .js file in `www` with a lot of the content from the one in `src/js` as well as what seems like a whole bunch of obfuscated code. Sorry if I'm going off on a tangent, but really confused.

Comment: the www code seems to be generated from the src folder, I suppose you use some build system like webpack, rollup or something like that, so you should work in src folder and then you should have some command that builds the www

Comment: Thanks @jcesarmobile. I've found a Gruntfile which appears to uglify contents in `src` and write them to `www`, so that probably explains that. Still trying to figure out how these changes then get transferred to `platforms/ios`, where there is the same repetition. It's all a big mess and there's no README, and this is my first day working with Cordova.

Comment: from root www to platforms/ios is transferred by cordova commands such us `cordova prepare ios` or `cordova build ios` or `cordova run ios`. (well, it's really just the prepare command what does the copy, but the other two call prepare internally)

Comment: @jcesarmobile I was afraid of that, since that gets me stuck again at the original problem: can’t prepare or build due to error and can’t remove/add platform due to there being version controlled code in there. Oh well, thanks for your help, if you’d like to summarise this in an answer, I’m happy to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not right to manually edit the platform files. And some manual changes might make the project not build, so might be related to the manual changes somebody did. So if you don't want to risk to remove the platform, continue building from Xcode

from root `www` to `platforms/ios` is transferred by cordova commands such us `cordova prepare ios` or `cordova build ios` or `cordova run ios`.

So if you can't do a `cordova prepare ios` because of that error you can try a few things.

1. Copy your files from `www` to `platforms/ios` without replacing the whole folder, just the duplicate files. `cordova prepare ios` is not just a copy, it's also does some modifications/aditions, but if you don't remove existing files it might work.
2. Create a new project and copy the `platforms/ios/cordova` to your own project and see if that fixes the mentioned problem, as that's where the Api.js file is.
3. Downgrade the Cordova CLI, try to latest 7.x.x and if it doesn't work, try with latest 6.x.x, one of those won't require the Api.js as it relatively new.